# Bluetooth pushbutton PCB or device?

Tags: pcb, bluetooth

I need the following simple device (to make or to find):

It will have bluetooth connectivity, one pushbutton and, obviously, batteries.

What it has to do is to send a message over bluetooth (the target will be a PC or a mobile phone) when the button is pressed.

Are you guys aware of a similar device? If not, can you recommend me the right components to build in a simplest possible way?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what types of bluetooth profiles your host software will accept.

Most bluetooth headsets have at least one button (hangup)

Mice have two or more.

Keyboards have lots.

Game controllers have a variety.  And remote controls, presentation widgets, etc.

Then there are bluetooth modules made for custom hardware projects...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at accent-systems. They produce bluetooth ibeacons devices with a push button.

Comment: This is a little short for an answer and we don't generally provide shopping advice.